# Is there any difference between where and join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two identical queries. In first I use `Where`

```
SELECT dings.id, doorbots.id
FROM dings
INNER JOIN doorbots ON dings.doorbot_id = doorbots.id
WHERE doorbots.id = 1615131 AND 
      deleted_at is NULL
ORDER BY dings.created_at;
```

In second I put all filters in `join`

```
SELECT dings.id, doorbots.id
FROM dings
INNER JOIN doorbots ON dings.doorbot_id = doorbots.id AND 
           doorbots.id = 1615131 AND 
           deleted_at is NULL
ORDER BY dings.created_at;
```

I have a composite index: `doorbot_id_idx btree (doorbot_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`

Is there any performance difference between this two queries?
What is the best way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that both approaches will give a closer performance, if not the same. Let the query planner do the dirty job. :)

The question is to maintain a **good readability** in your SQL, so in this case you must:

- Put filter expression on `WHERE` clause;
- Put only joining expression on `JOIN`. That is, only the relationship between the tables goes here.

Answer (score 1):

For `INNER JOIN` the alternatives are equivalent and any decent SQL engine will execute it the most efficient way whatever way you write it.

Personally I prefer to put only the ID comparison in the `ON` clause, while further filters go into `WHERE` clause.